# Merge two dataframes, with multiple entries put into a list in a cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df_A

```
id  status duration
1     C     1:00
2     F     3:00
3     D     2:50
4     Y     1:00
```

df_B

```
id loaded
1   grand
1   vice
1   cont
2   grand
2   bliss
3   test
```

I would like to merge these such that the result looks like:

```
id  status duration loaded
1     C     1:00    [grand,vice,cont]
2     F     3:00    [grand,bliss]
3     D     2:50    [test]
4     Y     1:00    []
```

With lists in the `loaded` column, but when I do a:

df_B.merge(df_a,how="inner",left_on="id",right_on="id")

I get something like:

```
id  status duration loaded
1     C     1:00    grand
2     F     3:00    grand
3     D     2:50    test
4     Y     1:00
```

Is this possible? And if so how?

Alternatively, what I want in the end to be able to do is to do a bar plot of entries in loaded vs the total summed duration, so if there is an alternative easier approach then that would be excellent.

i.e. plotting the following (obviously sorting out the units of the duration):

```
x=[grand,vice,cont,bliss,test]
y=[4:00,1:00,1:00,3:00,2:50]
```

**Update**

Actually on thinking about it, adding in a column to df_B so that I get:

df_B:

```
id loaded  duration
1   grand   1:00
1   vice    1:00
1   cont    1:00
2   grand   3:00
2   bliss   3:00
3   test    2:50
```

would be a lot more straightforward. I tried:

```
dd = {k:v for k,v in zip(df_A['id'],df_A['duration'])}
df_B["duration"]=df_B['id'].map(dd)
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: What does the duration represent? hours and minutes? Is it a string?

Comment: It was just an example. The dfs I have have a lot more columns in them - I have datetime objects which I use to get the duration in hours.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If you have the column as Timedelta, you can directly merge the two frames and aggregate (sum) the `duration` in a `groupby` (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df_A.merge(df_B.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(list), how='left')
```

If you want to add the `duration` column to `df_B` as I see in your Update: the way you do it does work. I m not sure what error you see.

The other pandaic way is:

```
df_B['duration'] = df_B['id'].map(df_A.set_index('id')['duration'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'status': ['C', 'F', 'D', 'Y'],
                     'duration': ['1:00', '3:00', '2:50', '1:00']})

df_B = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                     'loaded': ['grand', 'vice', 'cont', 'grand', 'bliss', 'test']})

### merge and group based on id
merged = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on='id', how='left')
result = merged.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['loaded'].tolist()).reset_index(name='loaded')

# merge the result with df_A
result = pd.merge(df_A, result, on='id', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your final result, you might want to convert the `duration` column to a `Timedelta` first, `merge` as is, and `groupby` on `loaded`, summing the deltas - no need for intermediate lists etc.:

```py
>>> df_A.assign(duration=pd.to_timedelta(df_A.duration+":00")).merge(df_B, on="id").groupby("loaded").duration.sum()
loaded
bliss   0 days 03:00:00
cont    0 days 01:00:00
grand   0 days 04:00:00
test    0 days 02:50:00
vice    0 days 01:00:00
Name: duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```